# codesandbox - /src/index.js executes twice

Tags: javascript, codesandbox

I have a codesandbox ( https://jjzlzn1jky.codesandbox.io/ ), all it has is a script tag with `src="/src/index.js"`.

In the index.js is `console.log("started")` whenever I reload the page the code is executed twice ( ie. "started" is logged twice to console ).

Any ideas how to stop this?

Here's the code !

```js
// src/index.js

console.log("started");
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>src/index.js runs twice</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <p>src/index.js runs twice</p> 
 <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can we see the source?

Comment: HTML / JS Added to question.

Comment: I mean, we need to access your codesandbox source.

Comment: Here it is.... https://codesandbox.io/s/jjzlzn1jky

Comment: It runs once in develop view, and twice in standalone view. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

This was formally an issue with CodeSandbox and not your code during one of the updates, but it's gone now.

[image]